# Determine if a given time is between start and end time

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I got two columns with Start and End times of shifts, I need a formula that returns if `NOW()` is on shift/off shift (eg. `TRUE`/`FALSE`)

[image]

Answers I found only using MEDIAN, AND+IF did not work as shift can start evening and finish day time. Anyone got an elegant solution for this?

Bare in mind cases when it is after midnight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged as [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) & [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba), you can use a UDF:

```
Public Function onShift(rngStart As Date, rngEnd As Date) As Boolean
    Application.Volatile
    If rngStart > rngEnd Then
        If Time < rngEnd Then 'After midnight & in-shift
            rngStart = Date + rngStart - 1
            rngEnd = Date + rngEnd
        Else
            rngStart = Date + rngStart
            rngEnd = Date + rngEnd + 1
        End If
        If Now >= rngStart And Now <= rngEnd Then onShift = True
    Else
        If Time >= rngStart And Time <= rngEnd Then onShift = True
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

But I would stick with worksheet functions as provided by Scott's answer.

The benefit of using a UDF however is that you are able to create easy-to-remember function names that does exactly what you need it to do.

Comment: it is a heavily macroed sheet so as long as it works i do not mind which way it is solved

Comment: it does not seem to work when time is after midnight. its 01:33 here atm :)

Comment: cheers. getting there, what happens at 22:20 if the start is 22 and end is 6. :)

Comment: @modzsi You really made me think on this question :). It's fixed now

Comment: I had no luck with formula last morning, and it is too late for me to figure this hence the question. Sick of it X) Try Start 6 End 14 Now = 22:20

Comment: @modzsi It's working for me. Press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Shift` + `F9` to force a refresh

Comment: @modzsi You can also try adding `Application.Volatile` to the function as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164445/discussion-between-modzsi-and-k-ds).

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
=MEDIAN(MOD($C$1,1),-AND(A2>B2,B2>MOD($C$1,1))+A2,AND(A2>B2,B2<MOD($C$1,1))+B2)=MOD($C$1,1)
```

You can replace all the $C$1 references with `NOW()`, or just put `=NOW()` in C1

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: proably the best answer. maybe the Q was mistagged,

Comment: hmm,looks good, but can you pls put 01:01 in C2 and replace NOW() with $C$2 in your formula?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have `=NOW()` in C1 (which will include date and time) you can use this formula:

`=(MOD(C$1,1)<B2)+(MOD(C$1,1)>A2)+(B2<A2)=2`

This works because if the time in `B2` is > the time in `A2` [shift is on one day] then the first two conditions need to be `TRUE`....but if the time in `B2` is < `A2` [shift cuts across two days] then only one of those conditions needs to be `TRUE` (or can be `TRUE`). Either way 2 of the conditions need to be `TRUE`

If you use this formula in C1 which will return the current time without date

`=NOW()-TODAY()`

...then above formula can be shortened to this:

`=(C$1<B2)+(C$1>A2)+(B2<A2)=2`

see screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=OR(AND(B2-A2<0,OR($C$1<=B2,$C$1-A2>=0)),AND($C$1>=A2,$C$1<=B2))
```

You can replace `$C$1` with `TEXT(NOW(),"hh:mm")` to evaluate the current time.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Considering all compared values are in `TIME` format, you can try:

```
=MEDIAN(A2,IF(B2<A2,B2+1,B2),IF(C$1<A2,C$1+1,C$1))=IF(C$1<A2,C$1+1,C$1)
```

If however you need to compare it with current time using `NOW()`, you have to strip the time out of it like:

```
=NOW()-INT(NOW()) '/* this goes to C$1 */
```

I saw how well Scott did it and the logic is way too high (at least for me) so I decided to make something where the logic is pretty straight forward.