# Caclulate if Now() is between 2 times across midnight Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I feel a bit noob asking this but been scratching my head trying to figure out a solution for this problem. (ADHD hitting hard as well)

I have a list of people  that are schedule to work  in various time segments, some of them with shifts that crosses midnight, and after comparing it with a different data set  know if the person if the person is  working or not.

1. **Column A** contains the list of people,
2. ****Column B** and C** contains the days off, combined with + =Today()
3. **Column D** contains the time when the shift begins, (As it time only, added =Today)
4. **Column E** contains the time when the shift ends,
5. **Column F** will indicate if that specific person is in their day off or they need to work, used the following code for it

   =IF(OR(B3=(TEXT(TODAY(),"ddd")),C3=(TEXT(TODAY(),"ddd"))),"Week-Off","Workday")

[image]

**In column G** I want to know if the person is working or they are absent after matching it with another table using this formula

```
=IF(F2="Workday",IF(AND(Now()>=$E2,(Now()<=$F2),"Scheduled","Off-Shift")," ")
```

So far the code has worked for everyone who has schedules that ends at 11:59 pm,  but when the shift ends at midnight or it crosses midnight  it provides incorrect  results (Shows Offshift instead of Scheduled)

In Short I want to know if =Now() is between 2 times, when is in the same day or the shift crosses midnight.

Code (Asume Now() is 1:30 am)

```
=IF(F4="Workday",IF(AND(Now()>=$D4,(Now()<=$E4),"Scheduled","Off-Shift")," ")
```

Expected Result

```
 Schedule
```

Actual Result

```
 Off-Shift
```

As on now i feel is a pretty easy solution but unable to wrap around a solution, and somehow my brain is focus on using IF. As an extra bonus if it can be done by Excel-VBA it will be a plus

Comment: Can you post the real value of the cells from columns Shift starts and Shift Ends? I mean the real value (the one you see in the **formula bar**) not the one you see formatted in the cell

Comment: I'm finding it a bit confusing - column C is headed 'Work day' but described in the text as one of the person's days off. Can you tell us what day the table was evaluated to get column F - by a process of elimination, looks like it might be Thursday?

Comment: @Tom typo  on my side,  collum C and B are  Weekoff not workday

Comment: @FoxFire unable to share real values as contains some sensitive info  but will share an edited version of it

Answer (score 0):

After looking a bit further found the solution in the following post:  [Determine if a given time is between start and end time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592619/determine-if-a-given-time-is-between-start-and-end-time)